# How to setup DNS?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, hosting

I registered a domain on uni.cc and I want it to point to a virtual server provided for free by some company.

I choose the DNS server like this:

[image: uni.cc form]

Then I have to fill in this confusing form in my virtual server's administration application:

[image: vserver pipni.cz]

So my question is: what should I type in the second form to make it work? (The values on the screen are the defaults.)

PS: Please excuse my pretty trivial approach to this matter, because I have no experience in this kind of thing -- I have always used the local server provided by VS and now it's time to move on.

Comment: May I suggest that BEFORE you try to set up anything on the Internet that you take some time to understand what you're actually doing. There are more than enough broken systems already.

Answer (score 3):

one A record should be good enough.
Add www in the second text box type CNAME and host value = @

[EDIT]
Example

@ - A - 217.16.*.*

www - CNAME - @

Comment: Sorry, I don't get you. Could you please write it more clearly. I should also add that the default values cannot be edited...

Comment: What do you mean by that 'www'?

Comment: updated the answer. Use the above values. Read help files from the hosting provider, they should have more details on how to fill the required information.

Comment: www mean www.yoursite will redirect to the address pointed by @

Comment: @ means http ://yoursite.com         www is for http ://www.yoursite.com